# Expected value of the sum of two dice.

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, dice

Came across this question:

We roll two dice. Let $X$ be the sum of the two numbers appearing on the dice.

1. Find the expected value of $X$.
2. Find the variance of $X$.

I'm not sure how to do either, but this was my thinking for part 1:

$$E(X) = 2((1/6)^2) + \\
3(2(1/6)^2) + \\
4(2(1/6)^2 + (1/6)^2) + \\
5(2(1/6)^2 + 2(1/6)^2) + \\
6(2(1/6)^2 + 2(1/6)^2 + (1/6)^2) + \\
7(2(1/6)^2 + 2(1/6)^2 + 2(1/6)^2) + \\
8(2(1/6)^2 + 2(1/6)^2 + (1/6)^2) + \\
9(2(1/6)^2 + 2(1/6)^2) + \\
10(2(1/6)^2 + (1/6)^2) + \\
11(2(1/6)^2) + \\
12((1/6)^2)$$

The reason I multiplied some by 2 is because it could possibly switch up or permute. So, for example, for 4, the two sums that could give us 4 are (3,1) and (2,2), so I multiplied one of the probabilities by 2 because (3,1) could come as either (3,1) or (1,3) whereas (2,2) can only come in one form.

Answer (score 4):

$$E(X)=E(X_1+X_2)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)=3.5+3.5=7$$

can you calculate $V(X)$?

$$V(X_1)=E(X_1^2)-E^2(X_1)\approx 2.917$$

thus

$$V(X)=2\times 2.917=5.8\overline{3}$$

Comment: That's what I got as well! The method I put in the question gives me 7 too. But apparently the answer is incorrect, so I thought I must have been doing something wrong. I haven't tried for V(x) yet, wanted to be sure of E(X) first.

Comment: @Nightwing : 7 is correct!

Comment: Hm, maybe my instructor has a mistake with the answers, I'll have to check with him on that. I'll try for V(X) now and include it in an edit in the question.

Comment: Confirmed.  $7$ is the expectation.

Comment: @Tommik So, to get the variance, do I just do what I did above but squaring the values? Like, (2,3,4,..,12) would be squared before multipling them? I did that and got 54.83, but it's also wrong apparently.

Comment: @Nightwing : see my edits

Comment: @Nightwing You did $\mathsf E(X^2)=54.8\dot 3$. That is correct, but not the variance.  You need $\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2= 54.8\dot3-49$

Answer (score 3):

What you have is correct so far.

However, a simpler approach is to write $X=X_1+X_2$, where $X_1,X_2$ are the values on the individual dice, and use the facts that:

1. $\mathbb{E}(X_1+X_2)=\mathbb{E}(X_1)+\mathbb{E}(X_2)$ for any two variables $X_1,X_2$;
2. $\mathrm{Var}(X_1+X_2)=\mathrm{Var}(X_1)+\mathrm{Var}(X_2)$ provided $X_1,X_2$ are independent.